# Swift coredata suddenly crashing app when calling fetch request

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

so i have been working on an app for the better of this year and have needed to use coredata, witch has been working until about a week a go. Since then i have tried every possible fix i could find to no avail. Making fetch requests and using the core data works on one page but there is one specific page that crashes every time, and im hoping someone could help me. The error message i receive is:

```
Thread 1: "+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name 'Link'"
```

and the code that i believe is the issue is:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct CreateWorkout: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var moc
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var type = ""
    @State private var workout = ""
    @State private var test_exercises = [Exersise]()
    
    private let types = ["Undisclosed", "Gym", "Running"]
    private let iD = UUID()

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            workoutDetailsSection
            
            exercisesSection
            
            createWorkoutButtonSection
        }
        .navigationTitle("Create your workout")
        .onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }
    
    private var workoutDetailsSection: some View {
        Section {
            TextField("Workout name: ", text: $name)
                
            Picker("Workout type: ", selection: $type) {
                ForEach(types, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var exercisesSection: some View {
        Section {
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    ForEach(test_exercises, id: \.self) { exercise in
                        NavigationLink(destination: exersise_info(exersise: exercise)) {
                            ZStack {
                                exersise_bar(exersise: exercise)
                                    .padding()
                                    .font(.headline)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: addButton)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var createWorkoutButtonSection: some View {
        Section {
            Button("Create", action: createWorkout)
        }
    }
    
    private func loadData() {
        var links: [Link]
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Link> = Link.fetchRequest()
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "setID == %@", iD as CVarArg)
        
        do {
            links = try moc.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching links: \(error)")
            return
        }
        
        for link in links {
            let request: NSFetchRequest<Exersise> = Exersise.fetchRequest()
            request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "exerciseID == %@", link.exersiseID! as CVarArg)
            
            do {
                let results = try moc.fetch(request)
                test_exercises.append(contentsOf: results)
            } catch {
                print("Error fetching exercises: \(error)")
                return
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var addButton: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: Create_exercise(setid: iD)) {
            Image(systemName: "plus")
        }
    }
    
    private func createWorkout() {
        let newWorkout = Sesh(context: moc)
        newWorkout.id = iD
        newWorkout.name = name
        newWorkout.type = type
        newWorkout.workout = workout
        
        do {
            try moc.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error saving workout: \(error)")
        }
        
        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
```

There is also a console traceback as well:

```
2023-07-18 21:56:32.676770+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b19380>
2023-07-18 21:56:32.677130+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b19380>
2023-07-18 21:56:32.677459+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b19380>
2023-07-18 21:56:32.689611+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b19380>
2023-07-18 21:56:32.689767+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b19380>
2023-07-18 21:56:32.691560+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b19380>
2023-07-18 21:56:32.692950+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b19380>
2023-07-18 21:56:32.775316+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b19380>
2023-07-18 21:56:32.775456+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b19380>
2023-07-18 21:56:32.775555+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b19380>
2023-07-18 21:56:32.775691+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b19380>
2023-07-18 21:56:32.775780+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b19380>
2023-07-18 21:56:32.777901+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b19380>
2023-07-18 21:56:32.778128+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b19380>
2023-07-18 21:56:32.786919+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b19380>
2023-07-18 21:56:32.787103+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b19380>
2023-07-18 21:56:32.787288+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b19380>
2023-07-18 21:56:32.787514+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b19380>
2023-07-18 21:56:32.787651+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b19380>
2023-07-18 21:56:32.787792+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b19380>
2023-07-18 21:56:32.787977+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] [SwiftUI] Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x600003b19380>
2023-07-18 21:56:35.423382+1000 SETS[31907:1389925] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name 'Link''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180437330 __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000180051274 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreData                            0x0000000184443d4c +[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] + 280
    3   CoreData                            0x000000018445b7c4 -[NSFetchRequest(_NSInternalMethods) _resolveEntityWithContext:] + 76
    4   CoreData                            0x000000018447c63c -[NSManagedObjectContext executeRequest:error:] + 164
    5   CoreData                            0x00000001843d3488 $sSo22NSManagedObjectContextC8CoreDataE5fetchySayxGSo14NSFetchRequestCyxGKSo0gH6ResultRzlF + 80
    6   SETS                                0x00000001045e222c $s4SETS13CreateWorkoutV8loadData33_2F24685CA2B8DA933B240E9DD9B9BEFBLLyyF + 912
    7   SETS                                0x00000001045e1e8c $s4SETS13CreateWorkoutV4bodyQrvgyycACcfu_yycfu0_ + 36
    8   SwiftUI                             0x00000001091d7ad4 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_37 + 1968
    9   SwiftUI                             0x0000000109620e3c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_16 + 4404
    10  SwiftUI                             0x0000000109adcb54 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_58 + 33080
    11  SwiftUI                             0x0000000109ad50f4 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_58 + 1752
    12  SwiftUI                             0x0000000109e43a44 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_35 + 23052
    13  SwiftUI                             0x0000000109e43a8c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_35 + 23124
    14  UIKitCore                           0x0000000105f52c00 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1860
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000187dfd528 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 440
    16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000187e08288 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 128
    17  QuartzCore                          0x0000000187d32130 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionEdPd + 440
    18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000187d5d0f4 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 636
    19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000187d5e518 _ZN2CA11Transaction25flush_as_runloop_observerEb + 68
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180399c10 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018039457c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 512
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180394a20 __CFRunLoopRun + 948
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180394254 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000188eb7c9c GSEventRunModal + 160
    25  UIKitCore                           0x0000000105aaeff0 -[UIApplication _run] + 868
    26  UIKitCore                           0x0000000105ab2f3c UIApplicationMain + 124
    27  SwiftUI                             0x0000000109b5b34c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_54 + 500
    28  SwiftUI                             0x0000000109b5b1ec OUTLINED_FUNCTION_54 + 148
    29  SwiftUI                             0x0000000109353474 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_16 + 88
    30  SETS                                0x00000001045de3d0 $s4SETS7SETSAppV5$mainyyFZ + 40
    31  SETS                                0x00000001045de4ac main + 12
    32  dyld                                0x0000000104881514 start_sim + 20
    33  ???                                 0x00000001049e1f28 0x0 + 4372438824
    34  ???                                 0x161f000000000000 0x0 + 1593992793112444928
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I am really hopping someone is able to help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator_. I think this is what you should focus on. How and when is the Environment variable managedObjectContext initialized?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thank you, turns out when i had some git issues a while back it had lost that bit of code.